# MS SQL: checking if a timestamp is after expire month(int value)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to find expired credit cards in a table. The fields `expire_year` and `expire_month` are **integer** values.

I was thinking something like this could work:

```
select * 
from CREDITCARD 
where CURRENT_TIMESTAMP > DATEFROMPARTS(EXPIRE_YEAR, EXPIRE_MONTH, 1);
```

The problem with this is that the definition of expired would be the first day of the *next* month. Therefore I need to find a way to write `EXPIRE_MONTH + 1`. But this is also no good, as the month might be December, in which case I'd be looking for month number 13. In such cases, I'd need to bump the EXPIRE_YEAR instead, and set EXPIRE_MONTH to 1.

I´ve tried to google to the solution, but my issue seems a bit too specific. In Java this would be easy enough to solve, but my SQL knowledge is limited to fairly simple queries.

Comment: Use `DATEADD()`

Answer (score 1):

Something like that :

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, DATEFROMPARTS(EXPIRE_YEAR, EXPIRE_MONTH, 1))FROM MY_TABLE
```

Comment: I need to declare the table in order to define the columns "EXPIRE_YEAR" and "EXPIRE_MONTH". I tried this, but it doesn't work:  
`SELECT *  
FROM CREDITCARD  
WHERE DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, DATEFROMPARTS(EXPIRE_YEAR, EXPIRE_MONTH, 1))+1, 0);`  
  
**EDIT:**  
I see now that EXPIRE_MONTH and EXPIRE_YEAR are VARCHAR(though they always have numeric value). Could this be the issue?

Comment: No, should work, Can you give me example input, output and your changed query?

Comment: If I copy/paste your solution I get:  

`Invalid column name 'EXPIRE_YEAR'.`

Comment: Why are you using datediff?? You only need to add one month.

Comment: Add `FROM` for example : `SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, DATEFROMPARTS(EXPIRE_YEAR, EXPIRE_MONTH, 1))+1, 0) FROM MY_TABLE`

Comment: @HoneyBadger, You have right ! I will change my answer :)

Comment: Thanks, both of you!  
  
I no longer get an error, but I don't get the result I want either(I get cards that expire between 2015 and 2021). I've tried to cast EXPIRE_YEAR and EXPIRE_MONTH from VARCHAR to INT, but it doesn't seem to work. Example:   
  
SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, DATEFROMPARTS(TRY_CAST (EXPIRE_YEAR AS INT), TRY_CAST(EXPIRE_MONTH AS INT), 1))  
FROM CREDITCARD;